# multiple bar plots for category data in a single plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have three categories data and I want to plot them within a single plot

Data are as follows:

```html
output<-read.table(text=" Class Out1 Out2
E Apple Orange
C Orange Apple
B Orange Apple
D Apple Orange
D Orange Orange
E Orange Apple
D Apple Apple
D Orange Orange
E Orange Apple
E Apple Orange
E Orange Apple
D Orange Apple
B Apple Apple
B Apple Apple
A Orange Apple
B Orange Orange
D Orange Orange
C Orange Orange
D Apple Apple
B Orange Orange
E Orange Orange
D Apple Apple
C Apple Apple
B Orange Apple
D Orange Orange
B Orange Apple
B Apple Orange
E Apple Orange
B Orange Apple
A Orange Orange

",header=TRUE)
```

I want to get the following graph which is a prototype representation of my data. I do not need to have A, B... at the top of the bars, but numbers at top of the bars are interesting.

[image]

Comment: What is your question? Also, where is your attempted code at solution? Please see [ask].

Comment: It looks like there are four groups - Out1 Apple, Out1 Orange, Out2 Apple, Out2 Orange - but you're only showing two in the chart.

Comment: @ cardinal40, thanks. If you look at df1, you will see three variables. I have melted it first, like this: df2<- melt(df1, id.vars='Class'), and then I used geom_bar in ggplot2, but it did not work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is probably some simpler solutions but here is one of those.

From your dataframe `output`, you can count for the presence of `Apple` and `Orange` in each output by using the function `table`. Then bind these two dataframe into a single one and transform it using `pivot_longer` and `filter` in order to be ready for `ggplot`.

```r
library(tidyverse)
# Couting occurence of Apple and Orange in each Out1 and Out2
o1 = as.data.frame.matrix(table(output[,1:2]))
o2 = as.data.frame.matrix(table(output[,c(1,3)]))
colnames(o1) = paste0("Out1_",colnames(o1))
colnames(o2) = paste0("Out2_", colnames(o2))

# Binding two matrix return by table
df = cbind("Class" = rownames(o1),o1,o2)

# Transform it in a longer format and filtering only rows of interest for ggplot
df <- df %>% pivot_longer(., -Class, names_to = "Variables",values_to = "Value") %>% filter(., Variables == "Out1_Apple" | Variables == "Out2_Orange")
```

Then for plotting the dataframe, you can do:

```r
library(ggplot2)
labels = c("Out1_Apple" = "Out1: Apple", "Out2_Orange" = "Out2: Orange")
ggplot(data = df, aes(x =Class, y = Value, fill = as.factor(Class))) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge()) +
  facet_wrap(.~Variables, labeller = labeller(Variables = labels)) +
  labs(fill = "Class")+
  xlab("") +
  geom_text(aes(label=Value), vjust=-0.5, size=5)
```

And get the following graph:

[image]

Hope it answers your question.